# PHP OOP Login System: IF ELSE Error

Tags: php, html

I am creating a login system with **OOP PHP**.

The problem is when executing the `if...else` statement where I check if the email is correct and the password of respective email is incorrect. If so, I display the error **Password is incorrect.**

However, the `if...else` statement is not working as expected. It returns no result i.e. `NULL`.

**login.php**

```
<?php

include('conn.php');

class Login extends Connection {
    private $dbEmail;
    private $dbPassword;
    private $query;
    public $emError;
    public $paError;

    public function loginFormHandler($email, $password) {
        $this->query = $this->DB_CONN->prepare("SELECT `email`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email AND `password` = :password");
        $this->query->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $this->query->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $this->query->execute();

        while($row = $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $this->dbEmail = $row['email'];
            $this->dbPassword = $row['password'];
        }

        if ($this->dbEmail === $email && $this->dbPassword !== $password) {
            $this->paError = 'Password Error';
        }
    }

    public function errors() {
        return array($this->emError, $this->paError);
    }
}
```

**And here's index.php**

```
<?php

include('class/login.php');

$err = [];

if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)) {
        $user = new Login;
        $user->loginFormHandler($email, $password);
        var_dump($err = $user->errors());
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="form">
        <form action="/oop/index.php" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <label for="email">Email: </label><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" required><br>
            <?php if($err) {echo $err[0];} ?><br>
            <label for="password">Password: </label><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" required><br>
            <?php if($err) {echo $err[1];} ?><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I am sending errors in a array and displaying the respective error.

Help me fix this.

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords in your database, use hashes.  See password_hash/password_verify.

Comment: I know. I am just learning some OOP stuff.

Comment: Where's your else?

Comment: Your method loginFormHandler does not return anything.

Comment: Can you show us what is outputed from `var_dump($this->dbEmail, $email, $this->dbPassword, $password);` before `if`?

Comment: @Progrock And it should not return anything, as errors are checked in separate method

Comment: As @Progrock quite clearly states: "***Don't*** store plain text passwords in your database, use hashes. See `password_hash` / `password_verify` PHP functions." . THERE ARE NO EXCUSES. If you make shortcuts with your practise work, you're going to make shortcuts with your "real" work. Don't be the problem.

Comment: Where is your database connection assigned? Have you checked your error log?  Does your query ever return a result?

Comment: If you successfully queried with a correct email but an incorrect password:  `Login::dbEmail` and `Login::dbPassword` would remain null as they never would be assigned.  Now read your if expression, it becomes:  `null === $email && null !== $password`.

Comment: @Progrock Thank you so much. I got it. Now, works perfectly. I just changed this `"SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email = :email AND password = :password"` to `SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email = :email`

Answer (score 0):

If in your code you take the email and password in the database it is obvious that the password will never be wrong (if it is wrong it does not take anything from the db = NULL). Your code like this:

```
class Login extends Connection {

    private $email;
    private $password;

    private $query;
    public $emError;
    public $paError;

    private function selectLogin(){
        $this->query = $this->DB_CONN->prepare("SELECT `email`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email AND `password` = :password LIMIT 1");
        $this->query->bindParam(':email', $this -> email);
        $this->query->bindParam(':password', $this -> password);
        $this->query->execute();

        return $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function loginFormHandler($email, $password){
        $this -> email = $email;
        $this -> password = $password;

        $result = $this -> selectLogin();

        if(is_null($result)){
            $this->emError = $this -> email;
            $this->paError = 'Email or Password error';
        } else {
            // do something
        }
    }

    public function errors() {
        return array($this->emError, $this->paError);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply check if row exist or not if exist start the session.otherwise redirect back with error
you can check if row exist by `fetchColumn()`
your login function should be like this

```
 public function loginFormHandler($email, $password) {
        $this->query = $this->DB_CONN->prepare("SELECT `email`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = :email AND `password` = :password");
        $this->query->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $this->query->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $res=$this->query->execute();
        $num_rows = $res->fetchColumn();
        if ($num_rows>0) {
            $row = $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo "success";
            //Do something

        }
        else{
            echo 'email or password is not valid';
            //or do something
        }
    }
```